# Exception repr type: what does it means?

Tags: python

Let's say I have this

```
try:
 #some code here
except Exception, e:
 print e
 print repr(e)
```

From this block of code I get

```
>>
>> <exceptions.Exception instance at 0x2aaaac3281b8>
```

Why don't I have any exception message and, moreover, what does second message means?

Comment: It depends on what `some code` is.

Comment: @JohnZwinck: is a more generic question. Don't focus onto code, that is bounded to a lot of logic that I haven't time to explain

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have an exception which produces an empty `str` (i.e. `str(e)` is empty).  Why that is cannot be known from the limited code you posted, you will have to look at the traceback to see where the exception came from.

As for `repr()`, that's intended to produce a string which may be ugly which allows reconstruction of the object, rather than pretty-printing.  It's not what you want for printing exceptions.

Comment: How can I look at the traceback?

Comment: `It's not what you want for printing exceptions`. - depends on the situation. I find additional info printed with `repr` useful

Answer (score 7):

An [Exception](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.Exception)-derived object is thrown in `# some code here`. This object has a `__str__` method that returns an empty string or spaces and no `__repr__` method.

See [Python Help](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__).

```
class SomeClass(object):
  def __str__(self):
    # Compute the 'informal' string representation of an object.
    return 'Something useful'
  def __repr__(self):
    # Compute the 'official' string representation of an object. If at all possible, this should look like a valid
    # Python expression that could be used to recreate an object with the same value (given an appropriate environment).
    return 'SomeClass()'

o = SomeClass()

print o
print repr(o)
```

Outputs;

```
  Something useful
  SomeClass()
```